# How to add different default route in GKE than to internet and make cluster still working?

Tags: kubernetes, routes, google-kubernetes-engine

I made a default route pointing to other VM in my VPC (for LB purposes) but since I cannot see my cluster working from GCP console (because cluster is routing all the traffic to my VM rather than to the Internet). Any ideas how to resolve that? What IP ranges should I add to route to the Internet?
I've whitelisted addresses from [docs health checks][1] but nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer [here](https://blog.softwaremill.com/setting-up-the-private-kubernetes-cluster-on-gke-the-working-one-e155ca18c113). Private cluster is the answer.